# issues importing ethers.getcontractfactory

Tags: javascript, ethereum, nft, ethers.js, hardhat

I am running a function that is supposed to mint an NFT from the browser.
I am able to execute the script from within node.js CLI . When I try to do it from the browser I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ethers.getContractFactory is not a
> function

Here is how I am importing it currently:

```
import { ethers } from "https://cdn-cors.ethers.io/lib/ethers-5.5.4.esm.min.js";
```

As I understand, "getContractFactory" is actually a hardhat helper. How should I import it? I am not using a compiler like webpack since I had issues with it.

Comment: have you tried seeing what is being imported by ethers?

Comment: how can I see what's being imported? If "getContractFactory" is a hre helper then I need to change the import right?

Comment: You can log what ethers, if its undefined then nothing is being imported.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `getContractFactory()` is a helper function which hardhat added to the ethers object and is only available in your hardhat environment.
The function is used to actually deploy a new contract.

What you want to use in the browser is probably `ethers.Contract()` to "import" an already deployed contract for interacting with it.

```js
const mintingContract = new ethers.Contract(
                    nftContractAddress,
                    ABI,
                    signer)
```

Comment: The user wont be receiving metamask prompts to sign. Everytime there is a request the transaction will be signed by the contract owner, so the "signer" is always the same. How can I obtain the signer from my address?

Comment: You are aware that the signer has to pay for the transaction? Further, for signing you need to provide the private key. Since you should not expose your private key to the frontend you would probably need to implement a server sided backend for you logic.